# Get value from dynamically created wx.checkbox

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

This code (thanks Mike Driscoll) creates a grid of 168 checkboxes, one for every hour of everyday. I am stuck when it comes to retrieving their values...
I would like to get a dict like {mon1 : yes} etc.
Any help appreciated...

```
import wx

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        for row in range(7):
            row_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            for col in range(24):
                name_of_checkbox = "row_{row}_col_{col}".format(row=row, col=col)
                checkbox = wx.CheckBox(self, name=name_of_checkbox)
                row_sizer.Add(checkbox, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
            main_sizer.Add(row_sizer)

        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Hours and days', size=(650, 400))
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a structure to hold the check box id's and add a button to retrieve all of the data at once. This makes it easy to access which boxes have been checked and which haven't. This way you can retrieve the data in any structure you like i.e. something like this:

```
import wx

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        days=['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
        self.boxes=[]
        for row in range(7):
            row_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            day = days[row]
            for col in range(24):
                name_of_checkbox = "{day}_{hour}".format(day=day, hour=col)
                self.checkbox = wx.CheckBox(self, name=name_of_checkbox)
                row_sizer.Add(self.checkbox, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
                self.boxes.append(self.checkbox)
            main_sizer.Add(row_sizer)
        button = wx.Button(self,-1,"Retrieve Data")
        main_sizer.Add(button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.OnChecked)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnGetData)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)

    def OnChecked(self,event):
        clicked = event.GetEventObject()
        print clicked.GetName()
        print event.IsChecked()

    def OnGetData(self,event):
        day_dict = {}
        day_list = []
        for i in self.boxes:
            if i.IsChecked():
                n = i.GetName()
                day_dict[n]="Checked"
                day_list.append((n,"Checked"))
        print day_dict
        print day_list

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Hours and days', size=(850, 400))
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need bind a event when the checkbox created. Then use the getValue() function get the checkbox status.

```
import wx

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        for row in range(7):
            row_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            for col in range(24):
                name_of_checkbox = "row_{row}_col_{col}".format(row=row, col=col)
                checkbox = wx.CheckBox(self, name=name_of_checkbox)

                #self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.onChecked)

                row_sizer.Add(checkbox, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
            main_sizer.Add(row_sizer)

        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)

    #def onChecked(self, e):
        #cb = e.GetEventObject()
        #print (cb.GetName(), ' is clicked', cb.GetValue())

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Hours and days', size=(900, 400))
        panel = MainPanel(self)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.OnButtonClicked)
        self.Show()
        self.user_dict = dict()
        self.initDict()

    def OnButtonClicked(self, e):
        cb = e.GetEventObject()
        print (cb.GetName(), ' is clicked', cb.GetValue())
        self.user_dict[cb.GetName()] = cb.GetValue()

        print(self.user_dict)

    def initDict(self):
        for row in range(7):
            for col in range(24):
                name_of_checkbox = "row_{row}_col_{col}".format(row=row, col=col)
                self.user_dict[name_of_checkbox] = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The output may like this:

```
(u'row_4_col_7', ' is clicked', True)
{'row_0_col_0': False, 'row_0_col_1': False, 'row_0_col_2': False, 'row_0_col_3': False, 'row_0_col_4': False, 'row_0_col_5': False, 'row_0_col_6': False, 'row_0_col_7': False, 'row_0_col_8': False, 'row_0_col_9': False, 'row_4_col_13': False, 'row_1_col_15': False, 'row_1_col_14': False, 'row_1_col_17': False, 'row_1_col_16': False, 'row_1_col_11': False, 'row_1_col_10': False, 'row_1_col_13': False, 'row_1_col_12': False, 'row_1_col_19': False, 'row_1_col_18': False, 'row_6_col_10': False, 'row_6_col_11': False, 'row_6_col_12': False, 'row_1_col_0': False, 'row_6_col_13': False, 'row_1_col_3': False, 'row_1_col_9': False, 'row_1_col_8': False, 'row_2_col_21': False, 'row_2_col_20': False, 'row_2_col_23': False, 'row_2_col_22': False, 'row_1_col_5': False, 'row_1_col_4': False, 'row_1_col_7': False, 'row_1_col_6': False, 'row_6_col_21': False, 'row_6_col_20': False, 'row_6_col_4': False, 'row_3_col_19': False, 'row_3_col_18': False, 'row_6_col_23': False, 'row_3_col_13': False, 'row_3_col_12': False, 'row_3_col_11': False, 'row_3_col_10': False, 'row_3_col_17': False, 'row_3_col_16': False, 'row_3_col_15': False, 'row_3_col_14': False, 'row_6_col_5': False, 'row_6_col_14': False, 'row_6_col_15': False, 'row_6_col_16': False, 'row_6_col_17': False, 'row_0_col_23': False, 'row_0_col_22': False, 'row_0_col_21': False, 'row_0_col_20': False, 'row_6_col_18': False, 'row_6_col_19': False, 'row_5_col_20': False, 'row_5_col_21': False, 'row_5_col_22': False, 'row_5_col_23': False, 'row_4_col_23': False, 'row_4_col_22': False, 'row_4_col_21': False, 'row_4_col_20': False, 'row_6_col_2': False, 'row_1_col_1': False, 'row_6_col_0': False, 'row_6_col_1': False, 'row_3_col_22': False, 'row_3_col_23': False, 'row_2_col_8': False, 'row_2_col_9': False, 'row_2_col_6': False, 'row_2_col_7': False, 'row_2_col_4': False, 'row_2_col_5': False, 'row_2_col_2': False, 'row_2_col_3': False, 'row_2_col_0': False, 'row_2_col_1': False, 'row_1_col_2': False, 'row_6_col_3': False, 'row_0_col_12': False, 'row_0_col_13': False, 'row_0_col_10': False, 'row_0_col_11': False, 'row_0_col_16': False, 'row_0_col_17': False, 'row_0_col_14': False, 'row_0_col_15': False, 'row_6_col_6': False, 'row_0_col_18': False, 'row_0_col_19': False, 'row_6_col_7': False, 'row_4_col_16': False, 'row_4_col_17': False, 'row_4_col_14': False, 'row_4_col_15': False, 'row_4_col_12': False, 'row_3_col_20': False, 'row_4_col_10': False, 'row_4_col_11': False, 'row_3_col_21': False, 'row_4_col_18': False, 'row_4_col_19': False, 'row_6_col_8': False, 'row_6_col_9': False, 'row_4_col_4': False, 'row_4_col_5': False, 'row_4_col_6': False, 'row_4_col_7': True, 'row_4_col_0': False, 'row_4_col_1': False, 'row_4_col_2': False, 'row_4_col_3': False, 'row_4_col_8': False, 'row_4_col_9': False, 'row_2_col_10': False, 'row_2_col_11': False, 'row_2_col_12': False, 'row_2_col_13': False, 'row_2_col_14': False, 'row_2_col_15': False, 'row_2_col_16': False, 'row_2_col_17': False, 'row_2_col_18': False, 'row_2_col_19': False, 'row_6_col_22': False, 'row_5_col_9': False, 'row_5_col_8': False, 'row_5_col_5': False, 'row_5_col_4': False, 'row_5_col_7': False, 'row_5_col_6': False, 'row_5_col_1': False, 'row_5_col_0': False, 'row_5_col_3': False, 'row_5_col_2': False, 'row_1_col_20': False, 'row_1_col_21': False, 'row_1_col_22': False, 'row_1_col_23': False, 'row_3_col_7': False, 'row_3_col_6': False, 'row_3_col_5': False, 'row_3_col_4': False, 'row_3_col_3': False, 'row_3_col_2': False, 'row_3_col_1': False, 'row_3_col_0': False, 'row_3_col_9': False, 'row_3_col_8': False, 'row_5_col_19': False, 'row_5_col_18': False, 'row_5_col_11': False, 'row_5_col_10': False, 'row_5_col_13': False, 'row_5_col_12': False, 'row_5_col_15': False, 'row_5_col_14': False, 'row_5_col_17': False, 'row_5_col_16': False}
(u'row_0_col_0', ' is clicked', True)
{'row_0_col_0': True, 'row_0_col_1': False, 'row_0_col_2': False, 'row_0_col_3': False, 'row_0_col_4': False, 'row_0_col_5': False, 'row_0_col_6': False, 'row_0_col_7': False, 'row_0_col_8': False, 'row_0_col_9': False, 'row_4_col_13': False, 'row_1_col_15': False, 'row_1_col_14': False, 'row_1_col_17': False, 'row_1_col_16': False, 'row_1_col_11': False, 'row_1_col_10': False, 'row_1_col_13': False, 'row_1_col_12': False, 'row_1_col_19': False, 'row_1_col_18': False, 'row_6_col_10': False, 'row_6_col_11': False, 'row_6_col_12': False, 'row_1_col_0': False, 'row_6_col_13': False, 'row_1_col_3': False, 'row_1_col_9': False, 'row_1_col_8': False, 'row_2_col_21': False, 'row_2_col_20': False, 'row_2_col_23': False, 'row_2_col_22': False, 'row_1_col_5': False, 'row_1_col_4': False, 'row_1_col_7': False, 'row_1_col_6': False, 'row_6_col_21': False, 'row_6_col_20': False, 'row_6_col_4': False, 'row_3_col_19': False, 'row_3_col_18': False, 'row_6_col_23': False, 'row_3_col_13': False, 'row_3_col_12': False, 'row_3_col_11': False, 'row_3_col_10': False, 'row_3_col_17': False, 'row_3_col_16': False, 'row_3_col_15': False, 'row_3_col_14': False, 'row_6_col_5': False, 'row_6_col_14': False, 'row_6_col_15': False, 'row_6_col_16': False, 'row_6_col_17': False, 'row_0_col_23': False, 'row_0_col_22': False, 'row_0_col_21': False, 'row_0_col_20': False, 'row_6_col_18': False, 'row_6_col_19': False, 'row_5_col_20': False, 'row_5_col_21': False, 'row_5_col_22': False, 'row_5_col_23': False, 'row_4_col_23': False, 'row_4_col_22': False, 'row_4_col_21': False, 'row_4_col_20': False, 'row_6_col_2': False, 'row_1_col_1': False, 'row_6_col_0': False, 'row_6_col_1': False, 'row_3_col_22': False, 'row_3_col_23': False, 'row_2_col_8': False, 'row_2_col_9': False, 'row_2_col_6': False, 'row_2_col_7': False, 'row_2_col_4': False, 'row_2_col_5': False, 'row_2_col_2': False, 'row_2_col_3': False, 'row_2_col_0': False, 'row_2_col_1': False, 'row_1_col_2': False, 'row_6_col_3': False, 'row_0_col_12': False, 'row_0_col_13': False, 'row_0_col_10': False, 'row_0_col_11': False, 'row_0_col_16': False, 'row_0_col_17': False, 'row_0_col_14': False, 'row_0_col_15': False, 'row_6_col_6': False, 'row_0_col_18': False, 'row_0_col_19': False, 'row_6_col_7': False, 'row_4_col_16': False, 'row_4_col_17': False, 'row_4_col_14': False, 'row_4_col_15': False, 'row_4_col_12': False, 'row_3_col_20': False, 'row_4_col_10': False, 'row_4_col_11': False, 'row_3_col_21': False, 'row_4_col_18': False, 'row_4_col_19': False, 'row_6_col_8': False, 'row_6_col_9': False, 'row_4_col_4': False, 'row_4_col_5': False, 'row_4_col_6': False, 'row_4_col_7': True, 'row_4_col_0': False, 'row_4_col_1': False, 'row_4_col_2': False, 'row_4_col_3': False, 'row_4_col_8': False, 'row_4_col_9': False, 'row_2_col_10': False, 'row_2_col_11': False, 'row_2_col_12': False, 'row_2_col_13': False, 'row_2_col_14': False, 'row_2_col_15': False, 'row_2_col_16': False, 'row_2_col_17': False, 'row_2_col_18': False, 'row_2_col_19': False, 'row_6_col_22': False, 'row_5_col_9': False, 'row_5_col_8': False, 'row_5_col_5': False, 'row_5_col_4': False, 'row_5_col_7': False, 'row_5_col_6': False, 'row_5_col_1': False, 'row_5_col_0': False, 'row_5_col_3': False, 'row_5_col_2': False, 'row_1_col_20': False, 'row_1_col_21': False, 'row_1_col_22': False, 'row_1_col_23': False, 'row_3_col_7': False, 'row_3_col_6': False, 'row_3_col_5': False, 'row_3_col_4': False, 'row_3_col_3': False, 'row_3_col_2': False, 'row_3_col_1': False, 'row_3_col_0': False, 'row_3_col_9': False, 'row_3_col_8': False, 'row_5_col_19': False, 'row_5_col_18': False, 'row_5_col_11': False, 'row_5_col_10': False, 'row_5_col_13': False, 'row_5_col_12': False, 'row_5_col_15': False, 'row_5_col_14': False, 'row_5_col_17': False, 'row_5_col_16': False}
(u'row_0_col_1', ' is clicked', True)
{'row_0_col_0': True, 'row_0_col_1': True, 'row_0_col_2': False, 'row_0_col_3': False, 'row_0_col_4': False, 'row_0_col_5': False, 'row_0_col_6': False, 'row_0_col_7': False, 'row_0_col_8': False, 'row_0_col_9': False, 'row_4_col_13': False, 'row_1_col_15': False, 'row_1_col_14': False, 'row_1_col_17': False, 'row_1_col_16': False, 'row_1_col_11': False, 'row_1_col_10': False, 'row_1_col_13': False, 'row_1_col_12': False, 'row_1_col_19': False, 'row_1_col_18': False, 'row_6_col_10': False, 'row_6_col_11': False, 'row_6_col_12': False, 'row_1_col_0': False, 'row_6_col_13': False, 'row_1_col_3': False, 'row_1_col_9': False, 'row_1_col_8': False, 'row_2_col_21': False, 'row_2_col_20': False, 'row_2_col_23': False, 'row_2_col_22': False, 'row_1_col_5': False, 'row_1_col_4': False, 'row_1_col_7': False, 'row_1_col_6': False, 'row_6_col_21': False, 'row_6_col_20': False, 'row_6_col_4': False, 'row_3_col_19': False, 'row_3_col_18': False, 'row_6_col_23': False, 'row_3_col_13': False, 'row_3_col_12': False, 'row_3_col_11': False, 'row_3_col_10': False, 'row_3_col_17': False, 'row_3_col_16': False, 'row_3_col_15': False, 'row_3_col_14': False, 'row_6_col_5': False, 'row_6_col_14': False, 'row_6_col_15': False, 'row_6_col_16': False, 'row_6_col_17': False, 'row_0_col_23': False, 'row_0_col_22': False, 'row_0_col_21': False, 'row_0_col_20': False, 'row_6_col_18': False, 'row_6_col_19': False, 'row_5_col_20': False, 'row_5_col_21': False, 'row_5_col_22': False, 'row_5_col_23': False, 'row_4_col_23': False, 'row_4_col_22': False, 'row_4_col_21': False, 'row_4_col_20': False, 'row_6_col_2': False, 'row_1_col_1': False, 'row_6_col_0': False, 'row_6_col_1': False, 'row_3_col_22': False, 'row_3_col_23': False, 'row_2_col_8': False, 'row_2_col_9': False, 'row_2_col_6': False, 'row_2_col_7': False, 'row_2_col_4': False, 'row_2_col_5': False, 'row_2_col_2': False, 'row_2_col_3': False, 'row_2_col_0': False, 'row_2_col_1': False, 'row_1_col_2': False, 'row_6_col_3': False, 'row_0_col_12': False, 'row_0_col_13': False, 'row_0_col_10': False, 'row_0_col_11': False, 'row_0_col_16': False, 'row_0_col_17': False, 'row_0_col_14': False, 'row_0_col_15': False, 'row_6_col_6': False, 'row_0_col_18': False, 'row_0_col_19': False, 'row_6_col_7': False, 'row_4_col_16': False, 'row_4_col_17': False, 'row_4_col_14': False, 'row_4_col_15': False, 'row_4_col_12': False, 'row_3_col_20': False, 'row_4_col_10': False, 'row_4_col_11': False, 'row_3_col_21': False, 'row_4_col_18': False, 'row_4_col_19': False, 'row_6_col_8': False, 'row_6_col_9': False, 'row_4_col_4': False, 'row_4_col_5': False, 'row_4_col_6': False, 'row_4_col_7': True, 'row_4_col_0': False, 'row_4_col_1': False, 'row_4_col_2': False, 'row_4_col_3': False, 'row_4_col_8': False, 'row_4_col_9': False, 'row_2_col_10': False, 'row_2_col_11': False, 'row_2_col_12': False, 'row_2_col_13': False, 'row_2_col_14': False, 'row_2_col_15': False, 'row_2_col_16': False, 'row_2_col_17': False, 'row_2_col_18': False, 'row_2_col_19': False, 'row_6_col_22': False, 'row_5_col_9': False, 'row_5_col_8': False, 'row_5_col_5': False, 'row_5_col_4': False, 'row_5_col_7': False, 'row_5_col_6': False, 'row_5_col_1': False, 'row_5_col_0': False, 'row_5_col_3': False, 'row_5_col_2': False, 'row_1_col_20': False, 'row_1_col_21': False, 'row_1_col_22': False, 'row_1_col_23': False, 'row_3_col_7': False, 'row_3_col_6': False, 'row_3_col_5': False, 'row_3_col_4': False, 'row_3_col_3': False, 'row_3_col_2': False, 'row_3_col_1': False, 'row_3_col_0': False, 'row_3_col_9': False, 'row_3_col_8': False, 'row_5_col_19': False, 'row_5_col_18': False, 'row_5_col_11': False, 'row_5_col_10': False, 'row_5_col_13': False, 'row_5_col_12': False, 'row_5_col_15': False, 'row_5_col_14': False, 'row_5_col_17': False, 'row_5_col_16': False}
(u'row_0_col_2', ' is clicked', True)
{'row_0_col_0': True, 'row_0_col_1': True, 'row_0_col_2': True, 'row_0_col_3': False, 'row_0_col_4': False, 'row_0_col_5': False, 'row_0_col_6': False, 'row_0_col_7': False, 'row_0_col_8': False, 'row_0_col_9': False, 'row_4_col_13': False, 'row_1_col_15': False, 'row_1_col_14': False, 'row_1_col_17': False, 'row_1_col_16': False, 'row_1_col_11': False, 'row_1_col_10': False, 'row_1_col_13': False, 'row_1_col_12': False, 'row_1_col_19': False, 'row_1_col_18': False, 'row_6_col_10': False, 'row_6_col_11': False, 'row_6_col_12': False, 'row_1_col_0': False, 'row_6_col_13': False, 'row_1_col_3': False, 'row_1_col_9': False, 'row_1_col_8': False, 'row_2_col_21': False, 'row_2_col_20': False, 'row_2_col_23': False, 'row_2_col_22': False, 'row_1_col_5': False, 'row_1_col_4': False, 'row_1_col_7': False, 'row_1_col_6': False, 'row_6_col_21': False, 'row_6_col_20': False, 'row_6_col_4': False, 'row_3_col_19': False, 'row_3_col_18': False, 'row_6_col_23': False, 'row_3_col_13': False, 'row_3_col_12': False, 'row_3_col_11': False, 'row_3_col_10': False, 'row_3_col_17': False, 'row_3_col_16': False, 'row_3_col_15': False, 'row_3_col_14': False, 'row_6_col_5': False, 'row_6_col_14': False, 'row_6_col_15': False, 'row_6_col_16': False, 'row_6_col_17': False, 'row_0_col_23': False, 'row_0_col_22': False, 'row_0_col_21': False, 'row_0_col_20': False, 'row_6_col_18': False, 'row_6_col_19': False, 'row_5_col_20': False, 'row_5_col_21': False, 'row_5_col_22': False, 'row_5_col_23': False, 'row_4_col_23': False, 'row_4_col_22': False, 'row_4_col_21': False, 'row_4_col_20': False, 'row_6_col_2': False, 'row_1_col_1': False, 'row_6_col_0': False, 'row_6_col_1': False, 'row_3_col_22': False, 'row_3_col_23': False, 'row_2_col_8': False, 'row_2_col_9': False, 'row_2_col_6': False, 'row_2_col_7': False, 'row_2_col_4': False, 'row_2_col_5': False, 'row_2_col_2': False, 'row_2_col_3': False, 'row_2_col_0': False, 'row_2_col_1': False, 'row_1_col_2': False, 'row_6_col_3': False, 'row_0_col_12': False, 'row_0_col_13': False, 'row_0_col_10': False, 'row_0_col_11': False, 'row_0_col_16': False, 'row_0_col_17': False, 'row_0_col_14': False, 'row_0_col_15': False, 'row_6_col_6': False, 'row_0_col_18': False, 'row_0_col_19': False, 'row_6_col_7': False, 'row_4_col_16': False, 'row_4_col_17': False, 'row_4_col_14': False, 'row_4_col_15': False, 'row_4_col_12': False, 'row_3_col_20': False, 'row_4_col_10': False, 'row_4_col_11': False, 'row_3_col_21': False, 'row_4_col_18': False, 'row_4_col_19': False, 'row_6_col_8': False, 'row_6_col_9': False, 'row_4_col_4': False, 'row_4_col_5': False, 'row_4_col_6': False, 'row_4_col_7': True, 'row_4_col_0': False, 'row_4_col_1': False, 'row_4_col_2': False, 'row_4_col_3': False, 'row_4_col_8': False, 'row_4_col_9': False, 'row_2_col_10': False, 'row_2_col_11': False, 'row_2_col_12': False, 'row_2_col_13': False, 'row_2_col_14': False, 'row_2_col_15': False, 'row_2_col_16': False, 'row_2_col_17': False, 'row_2_col_18': False, 'row_2_col_19': False, 'row_6_col_22': False, 'row_5_col_9': False, 'row_5_col_8': False, 'row_5_col_5': False, 'row_5_col_4': False, 'row_5_col_7': False, 'row_5_col_6': False, 'row_5_col_1': False, 'row_5_col_0': False, 'row_5_col_3': False, 'row_5_col_2': False, 'row_1_col_20': False, 'row_1_col_21': False, 'row_1_col_22': False, 'row_1_col_23': False, 'row_3_col_7': False, 'row_3_col_6': False, 'row_3_col_5': False, 'row_3_col_4': False, 'row_3_col_3': False, 'row_3_col_2': False, 'row_3_col_1': False, 'row_3_col_0': False, 'row_3_col_9': False, 'row_3_col_8': False, 'row_5_col_19': False, 'row_5_col_18': False, 'row_5_col_11': False, 'row_5_col_10': False, 'row_5_col_13': False, 'row_5_col_12': False, 'row_5_col_15': False, 'row_5_col_14': False, 'row_5_col_17': False, 'row_5_col_16': False}
```

Comment: Both of these work nicely, thanks. One more question, if I want to start with all boxes checked how would that be done?

Comment: Obviously I can do it with another loop, I was wondering if it can be done at the point the box is created...

Comment: Now I'm fretting about labelling the days of the week down the left and the hours (0-23) along the top. Nested loops give me nightmares!

Comment: @Floatingshed all boxes checked can be done within the initial loop. After defining `self.checkbox` add the line `self.checkbox.SetValue(True)`

Comment: Too easy! So easy that I overlooked it, I was expecting to have to do something far more complicated, good old python. And good old Rolf! Thanks.